# Having mistakes with Java Hashtable for a big input

Tags: java, hashtable

I'm making a code for this [HackerRank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/migratory-birds/problem), using `Hashtable`. My code passes the first 4 first input test, but when I try with the final one, the biggest, it reports a wrong answer.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

    static int migratoryBirds(int n, int[] ar) {
        Hashtable<Integer,Integer> birds = new Hashtable<Integer,Integer>();
        for (int i=0;i<n;i++) {
            if (birds.get(ar[i])==null) {
                birds.put(ar[i],1);
            } else {
                birds.put(ar[i],birds.get(ar[i])+1);
            }
        }
        Set<Integer> keys = birds.keySet();
        int maxKey = 0;
        int maxValue = 0;
        for (Integer key : keys) {
            if ((maxKey==0 && maxValue==0) || maxValue<birds.get(key)) {
                maxValue = birds.get(key);
                maxKey = key;
            }           
        }
        return maxKey;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] ar = new int[n];
        for(int ar_i = 0; ar_i < n; ar_i++){
            ar[ar_i] = in.nextInt();
        }
        int result = migratoryBirds(n, ar);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

And [this](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/33294/input04.txt?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJ4WZFDFQTZRGO3QA&Expires=1522959331&Signature=%2Bh6CiMYzKnzFSahLpWN3HKfk%2Bhs%3D&response-content-type=text%2Fplain) is the input (it's big).

Can anyone tell me why is this wrong?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

It is because of the following requirement

> If two or more types of birds are equally common, choose the type with the smallest ID number.

When using a `HashTable` the iteration order is not guaranteed.

Either add an explicit `if` check to pick smaller index when the counts are equal

```
 if ((maxKey==0 && maxValue==0) || maxValue<birds.get(key) 
    || (maxValue == birds.get(key) && maxKey > key))
```

Or use a `TreeMap`

```
Map<Integer,Integer> birds = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
```

The above works because of the *comparable* nature of Integers (and its natural ordering)